# Buttons with equal line-height in ALL browsers

Tags: button, cross-browser, css

I've been searching for answers, but unfortunately still havn't found one the right one..

I'm creating buttons using images and the button itself looks good in ALL browsers..

The thing is though that the text is placed differently (vertically) depending on which browser you are viewing it from. I've tried applying both line-height, padding/margin, top/bottom and several other attributes, but without success..

Isn't there a way (with CSS) to place the text correctly in all browsers? (Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari)... Don't worry about Internet Explorer - I'll apply some speciel CSS for this!

I've put up an example here to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/GydjP/1/

Comment: try setting a fixed height to the button, wrapping the inside text in a span or something with (only) a padding-top

Comment: Can you give an example of that like my jsfiddle?

Comment: button::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;} and adding Line-height actually does the trick for me in all browser except very old versions of Chrome and Firefox (where lineheight doesnt work at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}

and adding Line-height to the buttons is apparently the best solution I can find for my buttons so far.. It doesnt work in very old versions of Firefox + Chrome though

Comment: FYI, all versions of Firefox ignore line-height on buttons: http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/